# Difficulty in writing programs with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am going to calculate the product

```
acc = 1.44e-10;
a   = 1.732*acc;    
a1  = (a/2) * [sqrt(3), -1, 0];
a2  = (a/2) * [sqrt(3), 1, 0];
coordinates = [4.45714 0 0; %B
               2.22857 0 0.46152]; %A
R1 = coordinates(2, :)-coordinates(1,:);
R2 = R1 + a1;
R3 = R1 + a2;
R  = [R1' R2' R3'];
n  = dot(R,[ 0 0 1])/norm(R);
```

But I always get this error

`A and B must be same size.`

Comment: Please format the code properly

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen consider that done... :)

Comment: Check the size of `R` you are trying to make a dot product with matrix of different size when you do: `dot(R,[ 0 0 1])`. That's because `R1`, `R2` and `R3` are vectors not scalars, so `R` is a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: R = [R1' R2' R3']; Why is there three ' ?

Comment: in matlab the `'` in `R'` operator, will complex conjugate the matrix/vector. `.'` in `R.'` will transpose `R`.

Comment: @anahita : have I answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

When Matlab says *A and B must be same size*, it refers means `A` and `B` in `dot(A,B)`. In your case, this means `R` and `[0 0 1]`, respectively. In fact, `R` is of size 3x3, while `[0 0 1]` is of size 1x3.

Mathematically speaking, the dot product is only defined for objects of the same dimensions. Your objects (`R` and `[0 0 1]`) are not of the same dimensions.

Concretely:

```
R =

   -2.2286   -2.2286   -2.2286
         0   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.4615    0.4615    0.4615
```

You can take the dot product between `R1` and `[0 0 1]`; and between `R2` and `[0 0 1]`; and between `R3` and `[0 0 1]`. But you cannot take the dot product between `[R1' R2' R3']` and `[0 0 1]` because these objects are not of the same size.

Comment: I've edited my explanation; hope you understand it better now. If it's still not clear, please be more specific. Actually, I think the josoler's comment refers to the same thing I'm explaining ;-)